# What kind of singularity have $\frac{1}{1-\cos(z)}$ for z=0?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Set $\frac{1}{1-\cos(z)}$ and $z_0$. I cant identify the kind of singularity since the power series belong in numerator and I have tried with $$\frac{1}{1-\cos(z)}=\frac{1}{1-\cos(z)}\frac{1+\cos(z)}{1+\cos(z)}=\frac{1+\cos(z)}{1-\cos^2(z)}=\frac{1+\cos(z)}{\sin^2(z)}$$ but again have the same problem. And if is a pole how I find the main part for the Laurent series?

Comment: Did you try to express $cos(z)$ as a powerseries?

Comment: And then? @Aram $$\frac{1}{1-\cos(z)}=\frac{1}{1-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}z^k}$$

Comment: Expand the series a bit. And then use the definition of singularities for a Laurent series. http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/laurent.pdf see page 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac1{1-\cos z}=\frac1{1-\left(1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\ldots\right)}=$$

$$\frac1{\frac{z^2}2\left(1-\frac{z^2}{12}+\ldots\right)}=\frac2{z^2}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{12}+\frac{z^4}{144}+\ldots\right)$$

Observe the above already gives us a good look around $\;z=0\;$ and that's why we could omit so many terms in the power series of the denominator.

It is a pole of order two.

Comment: The sign for the coeficient for the last expression are all positive right?

Comment: How I prove the last assertion?

Comment: @Donyarley, it follows at once from the definition (or, in fact, it *is* the definition using Laurent series. Anyway, you have $$f(z)=\frac2{z^2}+\frac16+\frac{z^2}{72}+\ldots=\frac{2+6z^2+72z^4+\ldots}{z^2}$$ and the denominator above is entire.

Comment: I meant: How do I prove this
$$\frac1{\frac{z^2}2\left(1-\frac{z^2}{12}+\ldots\right)}=\frac{z^2}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{12}+\frac{z^4}{144}+\ldots\right)$$
Isnt tivial

Comment: I meant: How do I prove this
$$\frac{1}{\frac{z^2}{2}(1-\frac{z^2}{12}+...)}=\frac{2}{z^2}(1+\frac{z^2}{12}+\frac{z^4}{144}+...)$$
Isnt tivial

Comment: @Donyarley, at this stage it is almost trivial: $$|z|<1\implies \frac1{1-z}=1+z+z^2+\ldots$$and from here, since for values close to zero we have that $\;\left|\frac{z^2}{12}\right|<1\;$ ,we get $$\frac1{1-\frac{z^2}{12}+\mathcal O(z^4)}=1+\frac{z^2}{12}+\ldots$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$ \frac{1}{1-\cos z} = \underbrace{\frac{z^{2}(1+\cos z)}{\sin^{2}z}}_{=:f(z)}  \frac{1}{z^{2}} $$

and $f$ has removable singularity at $z=0$. (Just recall that $\sin z/z \to 1$ as $z \to 0$.) This shows that this function has a pole of order 2.

Answer (score 0):

near $z=0$  we have 
$$
\cos z = 1 - \frac12z^2 + O(z^4)
$$
hence the pole has order $2$, i.e. the function
$$
\frac{z^2}{1-\cos z}
$$
has a 'removable' singularity at the origin and approaches the value $2$ as $z \to 0$

Comment: I need a detailed expression for the Laurent series